# CSS control for multiple div's with different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement this
[CSS rating widget](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/star-rating-widget/#download)
into my web app that takes data from a db and displays it to a table. One of the values in the table is the span that contains the rating system:

```
<span class="starRating">
```

I programmatically create the span for each DB item:

```
            else if(dbArray[j].match('Rating')){
                var spanID = 'SPAN' + i;
                var ratingDiv = document.createElement(spanID);
                ratingDiv.setAttribute('class', 'starRating');
                var ratingContents = '<input id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><label for="rating5">5</label><input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><label for="rating4">4</label><input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" checked><label for="rating3">3</label><input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><label for="rating2">2</label><input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><label for="rating1">1</label>';
                ratingDiv.innerHTML = ratingContents;
                cellName.appendChild(ratingDiv);
            }
```

The spans each have a unique id, however they all use the same css.  The issue is when the star ratings are created I can only save one rating.  Is there a way for me to have the rating be unique in each case without creating seperate css for each DB item? Here is a crude example of the problem:
[JSfiddle showing what the issue is like](http://jsfiddle.net/alos31/bhpyk18w/120/)

Comment: advice: wrap ratingContents with single quotes, it will remove hell of \ and facilitate your coding mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

**html**

```
<div class="rating">
 <span class="star" data-value="5">☆</span>
 <span class="star" data-value="4">☆</span>
 <span class="star selected" data-value="3">☆</span>
 <span class="star" data-value="2">☆</span>
 <span class="star" data-value="1">☆</span>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //  Check Radio-box
    $('.rating .star').click(function (evt) {
        var $target = $(evt.currentTarget);
        $target.parent().find('.star').removeClass('selected');
        $target.addClass('selected');
        var userRating = this.data('value');
        alert(userRating);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: left;
}
.rating > .star {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.1em;
}
.rating > .star:hover,
.rating > .star:hover ~ .star,
.rating > .star.selected,
.rating > .star.selected ~ .star {
    color: transparent;
    2
}
.rating > .star:hover:before,
.rating > .star:hover ~ .star:before,
.rating > .star.selected:before,
.rating > .star.selected ~ .star:before {
    content:"\2605";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: gold;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhpyk18w/122/

I'm using this pattern, which I think is a lot cleaner (https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/).

Note that you're probably going to probably want to add something to click on to select 0 stars.

As stated above, you can't use the same id twice on the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems, but I think you're closer than you think. First you have non unique IDs, which is I think the main problem. IDs should always be unique.  I've made this jsfiddle, by just renaming id with letter prefix, and then a very small modification of your code made it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/v2575fg2/

For example:

```
<div class="rating">
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="astr5" value="5"><label for="str5"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="astr4" value="4"><label for="str4"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="astr3" value="3"><label for="str3"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="astr2" value="2"><label for="str2"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="astr1" value="1"><label for="str1"></label></span>
</div>
```

Then simply remove your removeClass:

```
 //$(".rating span").removeClass('checked');
```

And the ratings stick. Also instead of input click, I put span, it doesn't change much and makes it leaner.

Now you'll have to figure out how to lower rating...

EDIT:

To lower rating:

add to click event:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('checked');
$(this).parent().addClass('rated');
```

And this in css:

```
.rating.rated:hover span:not(:hover) label {
    background:#CCC;
    color:#FFF;
}
.rating.rated:hover span:hover ~ span label,
.rating.rated:hover span:last-child label
{
    background:#F90;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2575fg2/9/

Comment: Thanks @julien-grégoire let me give that a try!

Comment: that worked sort of but as you mentioned I can't uncheck.  I gave you an upvote though.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise if I have the wrong end of the stick.

Could you not create a class based on the rating and add that to each one also. `.rating5 { /* styles for 5 star rating */ }` ? Assuming the ratings are similar in nature and resolve to a finite number of possible outcomes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JohnDevelops.  I don't know how I would do that in this case because the widget does not have separate styles for each rating.  As the user hovers over the stars they change dynamically.